# Install Facebook SDK to Android Studio

Tags: android, facebook, android-studio, facebook-sdk-4.0

I am trying to install Facebook SDK in Android Studio project for 8 hours and still no success.

I was doing everything what I was asked in [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started/). So I did all steps but couldn't complete Android Studio Setup step 5. When I add this line in dependencies and then try sync it here is what I get:

[image]

And here are my repositories and dependencies:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        name "Fyber's maven repo"
        url "https://fyber.bintray.com/maven"
    }
    flatDir {
        dirs "libs"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
    compile(name: 'heyzap-unified-platform-10.2.0', ext: 'aar')
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:inmobi:6.0.0-r3@aar'
    compile 'com.fyber.mediation:applovin:6.3.2-r1@aar'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile project(':facebook-android-sdk-4.17.0')
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
}
```

Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@SilverBoy,

I think the errors you've posted and the `build.gradle` file paint a pretty clear picture of the error you're running into.

The errors you include indicate that the Facebook SDK requires the following dependencies:

- com.android.support:support-v7:**25.0.0**
- com.android.support:cardview-v7:**25.0.0**
- com.android.support:customtabs-v7:**25.0.0**
- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:**25.0.0**

If we take a look at your `build.gradle` file, you'll notice that you including different versions of *some* of these dependencies in you compile step.

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    // support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'   // <-- incorrect versions
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
    ...
}
```

I'd suggest, updating the versions of these dependencies to **:25.0.0**.  Also, you are currently missing the **customtabs-v7** dependency.  Add it as follows:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    // support libraries
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.0'   
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:customtabs-v7:25.0.0'
    ...
    // put additional dependencies here
}
```

Cheers!!!

Comment: Thanks, everything works just fine right now. Have a great day!

Comment: Good stuff & glad to help... could you +1 the answer?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. Because you need 15 reputation to give +1 and right now I have only 15. But as soon as I hit 15 rep I will surely give you +1